# How can I validate a website URL in Perl?

Tags: perl, url

I need a regular expression or module for validating the website URL using Perl.

Comment: You need to give more information. Why do you need it? What is "the website url"?

Comment: Why do you need to validate URLs? Where are you getting them and what are you doing with them.

Comment: @Jens I suppose website urls refer to those that include http or https service identifiers. Otherwise urls may include something like: news:alt.rec.motorcycle or gopher://gumby.brain.headache.edu:151/7fonebook.txt

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Regexp::Common::URI::http](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Regexp::Common::URI::http)

Comment: Website URLs can be either HTTP or HTTPS.

Answer (score 10):

I don't use regular expressions. I try to create a URI object and see what happens. If it works, I have a URI object that I can query to get the scheme (the other things get turned into "schemeless" URIs).

```
use URI;

while( <DATA> )
    {
    chomp;
    my $uri = URI->new( $_, 'http' );
    if( $uri->scheme ) { print "$uri is a URL\n"; }
    else               { print "$uri is not a URL\n"; }
    }

__END__
foo.html
http://www.example.com/index.html
abc
www.example.com
```

If I'm looking for a specific sort of URI, I can query the object to see if it satisfies whatever I need, such as a particular domain name. If I'm doing something with URLs, I'm probably going to make an object anyway, so I might as well start with it.

Comment: @brian, your script doesn't look quite right. I suppose without the http service identifier, www.example.com would still be a valid url but the script says the opposite.

Comment: A host name is not a URL. Without a scheme, www.example.com could be a host name, or a file, or something else. There's no magic that distinguishes any of that stuff on its own. It's the URL that gives stuff context and meaning.

Comment: Well, it seems Regexp::Common qw/URI/ does the same thing. But if someone should manually write down a lot of urls without http identifers, would those urls not be considered valid?

Comment: I think I just answered that.

Comment: @brian, I see the point. strict urls must include their service identifiers.

Comment: The things you call "Service identifiers" are actually called "schemes", which is why I keep using that term.

Answer (score 5):

Since you are talking about "a website URL", I guess you are interested in HTTP and HTTPS URLs only.

For that, instead of using regex, you can use the Perl's *[Data::Validate::URI](http://search.cpan.org/~sonnen/Data-Validate-URI-0.01/lib/Data/Validate/URI.pm)* module.

For example, to validate HTTP and HTTPS URLs:

```
use Data::Validate::URI;
my $url = "http://google.com";
my $uriValidator = new Data::Validate::URI();

print "Valid web URL!" if $uriValidator->is_web_uri($url)
```

And, to validate HTTP URL only:

```
print "Valid HTTP URL!" if $uriValidator->is_http_uri($url)
```

Finally, to validate any well-formatted URI:

```
print "Valid URI!" if $uriValidator->is_uri($url)
```

If instead, for any reason, you actually want a regex, then you can use something like the following to validate HTTP/HTTPS/FTP/SFTP URLs:

```
print "Valid URL!\n" if $url =~ /^(?:(?:https?|s?ftp))/i;
```

Answer (score 3):

```
 use Regexp::Common qw /URI/;
    while (<>) {
        /($RE{URI}{HTTP})/       and  print "$1 is an HTTP URI.\n";
    }
```

Comment: Website URLs can be either HTTP or HTTPS.